# Invalid Column Name for the non digit password

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a login application form using C#.

In the code below, I am getting an exception

> Invalid Column Name

when I used a non digit password. When I used only digit password it works perfectly.

The type of the `Password` column in the database is `nvarchar(Max)`.

```
if (ValidateTextBoxes())
{
   SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();

   oConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MCOEELIMENEM\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True";
   oConn.Open();

   string strQuery = "select id from Register where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password=" + textBox2.Text + "";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, oConn);

   var retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   if (retVal != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully Done");
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Access Denied, password username mismatched");
   }
}
```

Comment: Time to learn about parametrized queries.

Comment: 1) Your code is wide open to SQL injection vulnerabilities.  You may very well be experiencing the side-effect of that now.  2) Never, ***never*** store passwords in plain text like this.  User passwords should be stored using a 1-way hash so the values can't be retrieved.  Anything less is *very* irresponsible to your users.

Comment: And furthermore: I don't think a password should ever really be **1 billion characters** long - so please use a more appropriate, more suitable datatype than `nvarchar(max)` - don't just use `(max)` types everywhere because you're too lazy to determine the appropriate length!

Comment: I am curious why people are trying to close this question as 'too broad'. There is a clear question with a clear resolution, there is nothing broad about either. While I appreciate that his approach is far from ideal, please respect the rules of the site and deal with the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is not quoted correctly, try this;

```
string strQuery = "select id from Register where Username='" + textBox1.Text + 
"' and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

However, as others have suggested, you should really be using parameterized queries for a number of reasons.